# How can LeanFT be Usable in Agile toolkit?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, leanft

I Use UFT 12.02 Version & here I want to know that as per HP LeanFT document they says that HP LeanFT is more flexible in applying test automation in Agile Projects. Means with comparison of there previous Versions but I am unable to understand that how it is more capable to do that with Agile Projects point of view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more flexible as it is not a dedicated unit test framework, but rather an SDK that you can use in your existing unit-testing framework such as JUnit and Unit, this change makes it more pluggable into the existing build echo system (Jenkins).
In addition the SDK is provided in to 2 modern languages that is mostly used by developers (C# and Java) which makes it more suitable for Agile teams as the role of QA was switched into Dev-QA.

Finally there are 2 major IDE's (Eclipse for Java and Visual Studio for C#) that are supported out of the box with a plug-in which makes it easier to utilise the LeanFT SDK.